# migrating from rails 5 to rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

we are updating from rails 5 to rails 6. we are currently using the `ar_octopus` gem for database shrading.

Looks like the rails supports `database shrading` by default from rails 6.

I have updated the `database.yml` file like so

```
test:
  primary:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: test
    username: postgres
    password: root
    host: localhost
  main:
    adapter: postgresql
    user: postgres
    database: "<%= ENV['API_MAIN_DATABASE_NAME'] %>"
    host: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_HOST'] %>"
    password: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"
    database_tasks: false
    replica: false
  prediction:
    adapter: postgresql
    user: postgres
    database: "<%= ENV['API_PREDICTION_DATABASE_NAME'] %>"
    host: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_HOST'] %>"
    password: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"
    database_tasks: false
    replica: false
  onshore:
    adapter: postgresql
    user: postgres
    database: "<%= ENV['API_US_ONSHORE_DATABASE_NAME'] %>"
    host: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_HOST'] %>"
    password: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"
    database_tasks: false
    replica: false
```

If i run `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:migrate` looks like it still tries to run migration on all the databases.

`database_tasks: false` does not seem to work as intended.

may be i am missing something, is it not available in `rails 6`?

do i need to be on rails 7 for this to be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> database_tasks: false does not seem to work as intended. may be i am missing something, is it not available in rails 6? do i need to be on rails 7 for this to be available?

Yes, the `database_tasks:` option was added in `7.0` by https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42794

- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md